# Set different variable name for each iteration in html

Tags: php, jquery, html

This is my php and html code which update my page by fetching all the product names stored in database in a loop.
It just gives grey background for each even productname.That is why two li are there.

```
    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
   $qstr = http_build_query(array("productname"=>$row1['productname']));
   if($count%2 == 0){
  ?>
    <li>
       <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-4"> 
       <h4 class="text-center" id="productname1"><a href="productdesc.php?<?= $qstr ?>"><?php echo $row1['productname']; ?></a></h4>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-4">
       <img src="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row1['image']); ?>" />
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-2"> 
       <h4 class="text-center">Quantity :</h4>
       <div class="floating-box">
       <select name="quantity1">
       <option value="1"<?php if($row['quantity'] == '1'){echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>1</option>
       <option value="2"<?php if($row['quantity'] == '2'){echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>2</option>
       <option value="3"<?php if($row['quantity'] == '3'){echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>3</option>
       <option value="4"<?php if($row['quantity'] == '4'){echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>4</option>  
       <option value="5"<?php if($row['quantity'] == '5'){echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>5</option>
       <option value="6"<?php if($row['quantity'] == '6'){echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>6</option>
       </select>
       </div>
       <div class="floating-box">
       <h5><span style="color:#000000"> x </span>Rs.<?php echo $row1['price']; ?></h5>
       </div>
       </div>   
       <div class="col-sm-2"> 
       <h4 class="text-center">Rs.<?php echo $row['quantity']*$row1['price']; ?></h4>
       </div>   
       </div>
    </li>

<?php }
    else{ ?>
    <li class="bg-grey">
       <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-4"> 
       <h4 class="text-center" id="productname2"><a href="productdesc.php?<?= $qstr ?>"><?php echo $row1['productname']; ?></a></h4>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-4">
       <img src="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row1['image']); ?>" />
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-2"> 
       <h4 class="text-center">Quantity :</h4>
       <div class="floating-box">
       <select name="quantity2">
       <option value="1"<?php if($row['quantity'] == '1'){echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>1</option>
       <option value="2"<?php if($row['quantity'] == '2'){echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>2</option>
       <option value="3"<?php if($row['quantity'] == '3'){echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>3</option>
       <option value="4"<?php if($row['quantity'] == '4'){echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>4</option> 
       <option value="5"<?php if($row['quantity'] == '5'){echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>5</option>
       <option value="6"<?php if($row['quantity'] == '6'){echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>6</option>
       </select>
       </div>
       <div class="floating-box">
       <h5><span style="color:#000000"> x </span>Rs.<?php echo $row1['price']; ?></h5>
       </div>
       </div>   
       <div class="col-sm-2"> 
       <h4 class="text-center">Rs.<?php echo $row['quantity']*$row1['price']; ?></h4>
       </div>   
       </div>
    </li>
    <?php }
     $count=$count+1;
    }
```

I have jQuery function for checking which select option was changed and I am sending an ajax request using following function.

```
  $(function(){
 $("select[name='quantity1']").change(function() {
  var qty = $("select[name='quantity1'] option:selected").val();
  var productname = $("#productname1").text();
  $.ajax({
  url : url here--,
  type:"GET",
  success:function(html){
     //location.reload(true);
  }
  });
 });
});

$(function(){
 $("select[name='quantity2']").change(function() {
  var qty = $("select[name='quantity2'] option:selected").val();
  var productname = $("#productname2").text();
  $.ajax({
  url : url here--,
  type:"GET",
  success:function(html){
     //location.reload(true);
  }
  });
 });
});
```

Now the problem here is I cannot change my value in 3rd or any further product result because the id I have given is alternate.So,if I change my 3rd product result select value,it will still go to 1st as all **odd product result have 1 id** and **even product result have 1 id**.
Could you suggest me **alternate method to avoid this alternates** because it works fine for just 2 product result retrieved but not if retrieved result is greater than 2? 
Else could you suggest have **to generate variable id name for each iteration** and also same about the jQuery function?

Comment: You will want to do a triggering workflow that does not rely on hardcoded values such as an `id` like `"#productname2"`. You will probably want to use just a class as a selector and grab the data you need using `$(this)`.

Comment: You should be able to knock down your ajax to just one instance as well, there is no need for two, near-identical, ajax functions.

Comment: Just use your $count variable like this: `<select name="quantity<?php echo $count; ?>">`. And like Rasclatt suggested, add a class to your `<select>` and bind your ajax function to that class.

Comment: You can also make your options cleaner by using a function that compares two values, the iteration value and the input value. Then it will return `selected="selected"` if the iteration value equals the input value. You can also generate those options using a `for` with 1-6 as `$i` values.

Comment: Lastly, you only have to use `if/else` on this part `class="bg-grey"` of the `<li>`. No need to duplicate the whole code just for that little change.

Comment: @Rasclatt $(this) worked.Thanks!!

Comment: No problem, I have found `$(this)` to be a very important aspect of jQuery/javascript

Comment: Just one last thing how to add alternate background using just one li.I tried  li.nth-child(even) and li.nth-child(odd) but it seems to consider each div as it's child.So,how can I achieve alternate li with bg-grey.